# What is the definition of "set's worth," when used as a quantity

Tags: category-theory

What is the precise definition of "a set's worth" of something, when used in reference to the quantity of something?  Does it mean there is a bijective correspondence to the elements of some well-defined set (or perhaps a subset of such set)?

For example, in "Category Theory in Context" Emily Riehl on page 6 gives the following definition:  A category is small if it has only a set's worth of arrows.

Comment: I haven't seen it phrased that way very often. It's clear that her intent is that you don't have a proper class of arrows.

Comment: I agree with Derek Elkins, but I would add that the replacement schema of set theory is important in seeing why this kind of wording makes sense, intuitively. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement